# nodejs express serving folder and files stored in DigitalOcean/S3

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I would like to ask help on serving files stored via object storage in DigitalOcean/S3` using nodejs.

My current app checks the `./public/` folder inside the nodejs app folder as follows:

in app.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and in routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.render('home', { title: 'homepage' });
});
module.exports = router;
```

How can I let the app serve files located in the `./public/` directory in a bucket.

```
DIR   s3://my***/public/
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the purpose of S3, it's not like a database when you'll proxy calls to the data (s3) and hand it back to the client. Generally you'll expose the S3 bucket in a way that lets anyone view individual items from it but not index or update it.

From there you can just lookup the full file URL and pass it back to the user / browser / app. For example, I usually store the S3 location within my database, I'll then pull this out and append it on the end of the S3 bucket URL and then hand that back to the frontend to render my images directly from S3.

If you want to attach your own domain name to S3, you can checkout AWS Cloudfront and use the CDN feature. This allows you to attach your own domain name to the bucket and serve things up super quickly from anywhere across the globe.

Comment: thank you very much for your advice. I do not want to expose the files in bucket and have considered approaches such as [express-s3-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-s3-router),
which uses AWS config ( key and secret key) to access the S3 files. I tried that a little bit: accessing the first dir (s3://mystore/public/) listed in my bucket is fine, but accessing folder or files inside (e.g.: s3://mystore/public/dist/bundle.js) showed error.

Besides, AWS Cloudfront CDN is very interesting, I will try it tomorrow and might ask you more questions. Thanks.

Comment: If you're set on that approach then you could create an endpoint such as https://mysite/public where anything after /public is used to look up the file in S3 and you can proxy the file for them, but this seems like it'll increase the file load speeds significantly.

Comment: If you're trying to provide authentication to download S3 items then S3 also provides something for that. You can use the aws sdk to generate a sort of short lived key which you can use to serve up an S3 URL. This might be useful for content where someone must be logged in to access it.